# How to setup spring mapping if it conflict with real html files?

Tags: java, spring

I config spring and map it to *.htm, but it also applied to real .htm files. so i cannot access the real static *.htm in my web application. what should i config spring to solve the issue? thanks!

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>systemdispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

if i try to access the static htm file like index.htm, it will show a 404 error. how can i configure the spring to solve the problem? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the solution given by @Bozho.

But there is another way to do it also. You can specify the ResourceHandler that can serve the static contents from a specific path of your application without transfering the request to dispatcher servlet.

Try doing following configuration in your servlet xml file.

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

Here you can replace the path where your static .htm files are.

Hope this helps you.
Cheers.

Comment: Could you please explain where to put configuration above?

Comment: In your dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

Comment: but which part to put the line above? In bean tag?

Comment: I added it to dispatch-servlet.xml as below：

Comment: but i get error: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.sas.pdg.mrr.controller.UserController@5e34d46a]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?

Comment: I am not sure about that... I'm posting another answer to show the schema defination I am using in xml file. Please refere that.

Comment: I found i need to add one more line to make it work as below:
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>

Answer (score 3):

You can't solve it directly, because you have conflicting mappings. But you can have spring read the html file and output it to the user.

A suggestion, though, is to use `.html` for the static files and thus not have any conflict.

Along with this also you need to put the resource handler so that the static content gets skipped from the dispatcher servlet.

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

Comment: any other choice?  i cannot change it to .html either.

Comment: We can add <mvc:resources> to solve the static resource mapping problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set view resolver in your spring config file like this?

```
<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the above example change .jsp to .htm. After that your can use any url mapping in web.xml lime the one you are already using.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>systemdispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It will work because you will only give view name in controller and Spring mvc does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following schema defination in the xml file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
```

There might be the case that your spring version conflicts then replace the version with yours.